# Numbering by occurrence within a file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file below. I need to have the first field re-numbered by the occurrences of the 2nd and 4th combined fields. The 3rd and 5th fields are inconsequential. Thoughts? The input file is sorted by:
`sort -t',' -k2,2n -k4,4 -k5,5rn`

Input:

```
1,01053,11315,ABC,-38,Sin  
1,01053,11315,ABC,-88,Sin  
1,01053,11315,CDE,-114,Sin  
1,2003700,11314,ABC,-1,Sin  
1,2003700,11314,CDE,-44,unit  
1,2003700,11314,CDE,-72,unit  
1,2003700,11314,CDE,-694,Sin
```

Output I desire:

```
1,01053,11315,ABC,-38,Sin  
2,01053,11315,ABC,-88,Sin  
1,01053,11315,CDE,-114,Sin  
1,2003700,11314,ABC,-1,Sin  
1,2003700,11314,CDE,-44,unit  
2,2003700,11314,CDE,-72,unit  
3,2003700,11314,CDE,-694,Sin
```

Comment: Define 're-numbered'.  Is the new number strictly a count of successive instances of the same value in the 4th field?  What if it's the third in a row, but the value of field 1 in that record is 16?

Comment: Possibly `awk -F, -v OFS=,  '{$1 = ++n[$2 FS $4]; print}'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "_4th field in the 2nd field_"? It looks like you mean you want to count the occurrences of the combined 2nd and 4th comma-separated fields but that's not what you've written.

Comment: @roaima: I interpret that to mean that input `1,456,…,ABC`, `1,456,…,ABC`, `1,789,…,ABC` should be numbered 1, 2, 1 rather than 1, 2, 3. I’m downvoting the question for not explaining or illustrating that. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Another question for the OP: can the answer assume that the input is sorted? If so, is it lexicographic or numeric, or what?

Comment: @Eisen20 you should register [your original account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/234338/eisin20) so that you can edit your own posts

Comment: What do you mean by "_occurrence of the 4th field constrained by the 2nd field_"? Even though you've changed this from the original it still doesn't make any sense. What constraint are you now referring to?

Comment: @roaima The fields are separated by a comma. I need the 1st field to be numbered (1,2,3..) by the occurrences of the 2nd and 4th combined fields. The file is sorted by $2 and $4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the file is sorted according to the second and fourth fields, lines that need to be numbered in sequence are consecutive. So process the file line by line. If a line is within the same sequence as the previous one, increment the sequence number, otherwise reset the sequence number to 1.

```
awk -F, '{
    if ($2 FS $4 == previous) i++; else i=1;
    sub(/^[^,]*/, i);
    print;
    previous = $2 FS $4;
}'
```

Comment: I tried this and it returned a value of 11 for $1. What @StéphaneChazelas recommended in the comments gave me what I needed awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$1 = ++n[$2 FS $4]; print}'

Comment: @Eisin20, there was a typo in Gilles' code, see edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, Gilles' code is now producing the results I expected.